# zsh match files not containing dash

Tags: zsh

I have file listing as the following one:

```
001file.jpg
003file.jpg
001-800x600-sq.jpg
001-800x600.jpg
002-800x600-sq.jpg
002-800x600.jpg
003-800x600-sq.jpg
003-800x600.jpg
004-800x531-sq.jpg
004-800x531.jpg
005-800x531-sq.jpg
005-800x531.jpg
006-800x531-sq.jpg
006-800x531.jpg
007-800x531-sq.jpg
007-800x531.jpg
008-800x1067-sq.jpg
008-800x1067.jpg
009-800x1067-sq.jpg
009-800x1067.jpg
010-800x533-sq.jpg
010-800x533.jpg
011-800x1200-sq.jpg
011-800x1200.jpg
012-800x533-sq.jpg
012-800x533.jpg
013-800x600-sq.jpg
013-800x600.jpg
014-800x1067-sq.jpg
014-800x1067.jpg
015-800x533-sq.jpg
015-800x533.jpg
016-800x533-sq.jpg
016-800x533.jpg
```

In ZSH, I want to list all files beginning with any number, not containing dash in filename, so I tried:

```
print -l <->[^-]*.jpg
```

with no success. What is wrong with this pattern!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, I think, similar to the case that the documentation for `<->` warns about:

> Be careful when using other wildcards adjacent to patterns of this form; for example, <0-9>* will  actually  match  any  number  whatsoever  at the start of the string, since the `<0-9>' will match the first
>                 digit, and the `*' will match any others.  This is a trap for the unwary, but is in fact  an  inevitable
>                 consequence  of  the  rule  that  the  longest  possible  match  always  succeeds.   Expressions such as
>                 `<0-9>[^[:digit:]]*' can be used instead.

In `print -l <->[^-]*.jpg`, the `<->` matches the first digit, then `[^-]` matches the 2nd digit, and `*` matches everything thing else.

Use instead

```
print -l <->[^[:digit:]-]*.jpg
```